# RewriteRule to convert /a/b into ?x=a&y=b?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current rewrite rule, which lets me pass a url like **domain.com/pagename** and it will evaluate it into **domain.com/index.php?page=pagename**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

What do I need to do/add in there to allow it to take a URL like this:

**domain.com/pagename/type/value**

and evaluate it into this:

**domain.com/index.php?page=pagename&t=type&v=value**

(where both /type and /value are optional)

??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# If the request is for a valid file - OR
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# then do nothing thus ignore all rules below this rule
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# one parameter rule with numbers
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

# one parameter rule
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

# two parameter rule
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA]

# three parameter rule
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&t=$2&v=$3 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Beauty! That's exactly it! What does that RewriteRule ^ - [L] line do again?

Comment: How would you change that to accept either /pagename or /43 (integer) and evaluate those into either /index.php?page=pagename or /index.php?value=43?

Comment: Question - how would I account for the case when I have a call like "www.user.domain.com" instead of "user.domain.com", where user is a subfolder like domain.com/user, and this .htaccess is placed inside that folder. This works great for non "www" calls, but once the "www." part is added (by unsuspecting visitors) it breaks the whole logic down and passes "www.user" as the query parameter.

Comment: it's typed in by the user itself, manually, as in user error, but I'd like to account for that error in the rules/website itself instead of have a silly user break the whole thing and then start complaining how it doesn't work...

Comment: Let's take it up on your new question. I asked a question for you.